# Connect Asterisk to Exchange shared mailbox via IMAP

Tags: email, exchange, imap, asterisk

We have been tasked with connecting Asterisk VM to our exchange environment so that Asterisk can drop a .wav file of the received v/m into a shared mailbox. We have been given the settings needed by the asterisk admin which are below :

mapgreetings=no
greetingsfolder=INBOX
imapparentfolder=INBOX
imapserver=localhost
imapport=143
imapflags=ssl
imapfolder=INBOX
authuser=user
authpassword=password
imapopentimeout=60
imapclosetimeout=60
imapreadtimeout=60
imapwritetimeout=60
imap_poll_logout=no

My questions are as follows

1. can this be done with an account that has impersonation rights, so that we do not provide the user name and password to a shared mailbox? If not we would have to enable the AD user account for the shared mailbox and provide it.
2. Is the password stored in the config file as plain text?
3. Is there a way to secure the password if it is?
4. (Assumption) IMAP must be enabled on the exchange servers?
5. can the imapserver be the smtp relay or must it be the ip address of one of the actual exchange servers?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/impersonation-and-ews-in-exchange), you can use impersonation to access multiple mailboxes without providing the user name and password for each mailbox. However, you need to grant the ApplicationImpersonation role to the account that will use impersonation, and create a management scope that limits impersonation to a specified group of accounts. You also need to configure your Asterisk application to use impersonation when connecting to the Exchange server.

If you store the password in the config file, it will be in plain text unless you encrypt it. This is not a secure practice, as anyone who can read the file can get your credentials. You should avoid storing passwords in config files if possible, or use encryption to protect them.

There are different ways to secure the password in the config file, such as using encryption, encoding, or the kernel key retention service. However, none of these methods are foolproof, as an attacker who can access the server can also decrypt, decode, or retrieve the password in the same way the application does. You can also use detective controls, such as auditing and monitoring the access to the file, to improve the security posture.

Yes, IMAP must be enabled on the Exchange servers for Asterisk to connect to them. You can enable IMAP on the Exchange admin center or using PowerShell commands. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/plan-and-deploy/deploy-new-installations/create-azure-test-environments?view=exchserver-2019

The imapserver can be either the smtp relay or the IP address of one of the actual Exchange servers, as long as it can resolve to the Exchange server that hosts the mailbox. You can also use the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) of the Exchange server.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

On the Exchange side:

1. Yes, generally the account handling imap is or can be separate from the destination mailbox. Many "unified messaging" voicemail systems use one user account to insert notifications for all phone users

4. Yes, IMAP must be enabled to use it

5. If your SMTP relay *also* relays IMAP (port 143) traffic, then yes you can use that address

---

If you only need the .wav emails, then you might just want to use SMTP notifications and relay those through exchange instead. Enabling/configuring IMAP is usually only necessary if you need to synchronize read/unread/deleted status with a voice mailbox